# Customize Chrome settings page

Tags: google-chrome, css, chromium

This is normal Chrome settings page:
[image: Chrome Settings]

I customized this page using simple edit in Chrome developer tools like this: 
[image: Customized Chrome page]

I want my chrome settings page in this way. So I'm trying to keep this setting page permanent. How can I do that?

Edit: Got the idea based on adding the following code on the file `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` gives me ability to see always the advanced settings in chrome without clicking.

```
body.uber-frame #advanced-settings {
display: block !important;
height: auto !important;
}
```

Edit2: The article is here: http://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/How-do-I-show-Google-Chrome-advanced-settings-by-default

Thus still I'm looking for similar tweak for me.

Comment: You modified the page with developer tools from the settings menu, correct? Those only modify the local DOM elements. To permanently modify Chrome you would need to download the Chromium source and modify that.

Comment: I have seen a tweak, that modifying the %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css file gives option to "Always show advanced settings". Hence I assumed it's possible.

Comment: I had seen articles about using custom css to modify viewing a website in Chrome but not Chrome itself. Looks like you might have answered your own question. You should add that as an answer if so.

Comment: Well, I've linked above, which tunes Chrome's behavior, not just websites.